# How to run this subquery in Laravel 5.4 and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, subquery

I need to run this subquery in Laravel 5.4 and the answers that I have found on StackOverflow are for Laravel <5.

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
                    FROM (
                           SELECT DISTINCT
                             testing_results.pluginName,
                             SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cvss_vector, '#', -1), '/', 1) AS access_vector,
                             SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cvss_vector, '/', 2), '/', -1) AS access_complexity,
                             SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cvss_vector, '/', 3), '/', -1) AS authentication,
                             SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cvss_vector, '/', 4), '/', -1) AS confidentiality,
                             SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cvss_vector, '/', 5), '/', -1) AS integrity,
                             SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cvss_vector, '/', 6), '/', -1) AS availability
                           FROM
                             testing_results
                           WHERE
                             testing_results.cvss_vector != ''
                         ) sub
                         WHERE sub.access_vector LIKE '%AV:L%'
```

Thank you very in advanced for your help.

Best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way to do this is:

```
$query = <<<SQL
SELECT DISTINCT *
                FROM (
                       SELECT DISTINCT
                         testing_results.pluginName,
                         SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cvss_vector, '#', -1), '/', 1) AS access_vector,
                         SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cvss_vector, '/', 2), '/', -1) AS access_complexity,
                         SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cvss_vector, '/', 3), '/', -1) AS authentication,
                         SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cvss_vector, '/', 4), '/', -1) AS confidentiality,
                         SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cvss_vector, '/', 5), '/', -1) AS integrity,
                         SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cvss_vector, '/', 6), '/', -1) AS availability
                       FROM
                         testing_results
                       WHERE
                         testing_results.cvss_vector != ''
                     ) sub
                     WHERE sub.access_vector LIKE '%AV:L%'
SQL;

dd(DB::select($query));
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! There's one more thing that I'd like to do, I'd like to count the results but when I try to call the method `count();` like this `DB::select($query)->count();` it doesn't works. Could you please point me in the right direction? Again, thanks!

Comment: @SecretCoder you can convert it to collection and then use familiar methods: `collect(DB::select($query))->count()`, or work with it as a normal array: `count(DB::select($query))`.

Answer (score 0):

//Building Inner Query

```
$sub_query = DB::table('testing_results')
->select([DB::raw('DISTINCT testing_results.pluginName'),
DB::raw('SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cvss_vector, '#', -1), '/', 1) AS access_vector'),
DB::raw('SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cvss_vector, '/', 2), '/', -1) AS access_complexity'),
DB::raw('SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cvss_vector, '/', 3), '/', -1) AS authentication'),
DB::raw('SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cvss_vector, '/', 4), '/', -1) AS confidentiality'),
DB::raw('SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cvss_vector, '/', 5), '/', -1) AS integrity'),
DB::raw('SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cvss_vector, '/', 6), '/', -1) AS availability')
])
->where('testing_results.cvss_vector', '!=', '');
```

//Creating Outer Query

```
$query = DB::raw("({$sub_query->toSql()}) as sub_query");
$data = DB::table($query)
         ->mergeBindings($sub_query)
         ->where('access_vector', 'NOT LIKE', '%AV:L%')->get();
```

Note : This works on Laravel 5.2, which means it will work on Laravel 5.4.